# Ansible - Reduce on screen outputs

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

I have below task in my playbook, which generates lots of outputs on the screen. Is there a way to hide those lines (e.g. `ok: [LAB_RT03] => (item=show runn)` on-screen? Items in the file are list of show commands to run on network devices. In reality there will be 10's of commands.

The task

```yaml
- name: "retrieve show commands  from Routers "
 ios_command:
   commands: 
   - command: "{{ item }}"
 loop: "{{ lookup('file', './commands/ios_commands.txt').splitlines() }}"
 register: ios_output
 ignore_errors: true
 when: ansible_network_os == 'ios'
```

Outputs:

```
ok: [LAB_RT03] => (item=show runn)
ok: [LAB_RT04] => (item=show runn)
ok: [LAB_RT04] => (item=show version)
ok: [LAB_RT03] => (item=show version)
ok: [LAB_RT04] => (item=show ip route vrf ext)
ok: [LAB_RT03] => (item=show ip route vrf ext)
```

Comment: if you could use `shell` over `command` then , replace `- command:"{{ item }}"` with `- shell:  "{{ item }} &>/dev/null"`

Comment: I am not sure if [Adding Loop Controls](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops) will provide you the expected result. You may just try.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your playbook loop control label 'LAB_RTO3' as following the example you can limit the displayed output.

```
- name: "retrieve show commands  from Routers "
 ios_command:
   commands: 
   - command: "{{ item }}"
 loop: "{{ lookup('file', './commands/ios_commands.txt').splitlines() }}"
 loop_control:
   label: "{{ LAB_RT03 }}"
 register: ios_output
 ignore_errors: true
 when: ansible_network_os == 'ios'
```